# How to store user meta information for different user role in database laravel

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent

I have different roles in my laravel application as doctor, patient, admin. Each one of them have different information as patient have the information about blood group, gender, infection and so on(many other fields) but doctor and admin will not have these. Doctor will have fields which patient and admin can't have. So how can I store such information in the database in better way. (I would like to retrieve the information based on these fields also).

- I was thinking about to create new table `user_meta` and add columns as
  `user_id`, `key`, `value`.
- The second option is to have the field in `users` table as `meta`
  with JSON object which will store all the information about the user

The first approach is good for searching but bad for huge record and the second is good for huge record but bad for searching. So what do you think is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

The second method isn't also bad for searching. Store the values in json format
{ gender: "male", blood:" O+" }......

Laravel already have a built in formated that nice help you search through such data 
E.g
$value->data['gender'];

Comment: let suppose I want to fetch all the record which have `gender` male in table, then? how should I write the query?